# Convert CESU-8 to UTF-8 with high performance

Tags: php, performance, unicode, utf-8, cesu-8

I have some raw text that is usually a valid UTF-8 string. However, every now and then it turns out that the input is in fact a CESU-8 string, instead. It is possible to technically detect this and convert to UTF-8 but as this happens rarely, I would rather not spend lots of CPU time to do this.

Is there any **fast** method to detect if a string is encoded with CESU-8 or UTF-8? I guess I could always blindly convert "UTF-8" to UTF-16LE and then to UTF-8 using `iconv()` and I would probably get the correct result every time because CESU-8 is close enough to UTF-8 for this to work. **Can you suggest anything faster?** (I'm expecting the input string to be CESU-8 instead of valid UTF-8 around 0.01-0.1% of all string occurrences.)

*(CESU-8 is a non-standard string format which contains 16-bit surrogate pairs encoded in UTF-8. Technically UTF-8 strings should contain the characters represented by those surrogate pairs, not the surrogate pairs itself.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more efficient version of your conversion function:

```
$regex = '@(\xED[\xA0-\xAF][\x80-\xBF]\xED[\xB0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF])@';
$s = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($m) {
    $in = unpack("C*", $m[0]);
    $in[2] += 1; // Effectively adds 0x10000 to the codepoint.
    return pack("C*",
        0xF0 | (($in[2] & 0x1C) >> 2),
        0x80 | (($in[2] & 0x03) << 4) | (($in[3] & 0x3C) >> 2),
        0x80 | (($in[3] & 0x03) << 4) | ($in[5] & 0x0F),
        $in[6]
    );
}, $s);
```

The code only converts high surrogates followed by low surrogates, and converts the two three-byte CESU-8 sequences directly into a four-byte UTF-8 sequence, i.e. from

```
ED       A0-AF    80-BF    ED       B0-BF    80-BF
11101101 1010aaaa 10bbbbbb 11101101 1011cccc 10dddddd
```

to

```
F0-F4    80-BF    80-BF    80-BF
11110oaa 10aabbbb 10bbcccc 10dddddd    // o is "overflow" bit
```

Here's an [online example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1bdfc54a4f18dcefe6a11a14b4830962555d391).

Answer (score 3):

CESU-8 strings will encode surrogate pairs using the byte sequence:

```
ED [A0..BF] [80..BF]
```

That is: `0xED`, followed by any byte between `0xA0` and `0xBF` (inclusive), followed by any byte between `0x80` and `0xBF` (inclusive).

Such a sequence of bytes cannot appear in any valid UTF-8 string, and are the only bytes allowed to appear in CESU-8 in excess of UTF-8. Checking for such a byte sequence should reliably detect CESU-8, and *may* be faster than decoding the entire string.

Comment: I think I need to go with regex for detection and converting the string in a loop because neither `iconv()` nor `mb_convert_encoding()` are willing to accept CESU-8 input.

Answer (score 1):

The intl [UConverter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.uconverter.php) class seems to be able to handle CESU-8 (unlike mbstring).

```php
$converter = new \UConverter('UTF-8', 'CESU-8');
echo $converter->convert("\xED\xA0\xBD\xED\xB8\x80");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation I'm currently using:

```php
/**
 * @param string $s raw input with UTF-8 or CESU-8 encoding
 * @return string input with UTF-8 encoding
 * @license MIT
 */
protected function verifyValidUtf8($s)
{
    $s = preg_replace_callback('@(?:\xED[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]){2}@', function ($m)
    {
        $bytes = unpack("C*", $m[0]); # always 6 bytes

        # create UCS-4 character from CESU-8 encoded surrogate pair in $bytes

        # 3 bytes CESU-8 to UNICODE high surrogate:
        $high = (($bytes[1] & 0x0F) << 12) + (($bytes[2] & 0x3F) << 6) + ($bytes[3] & 0x3F);
        # 3 bytes CESU-8 to UNICODE low surrogate:
        $low = (($bytes[4] & 0x0F) << 12) + (($bytes[5] & 0x3F) << 6) + ($bytes[6] & 0x3F);

        $codepoint = ($high & 0x03FF) << 10 | ($low & 0x03FF);
        $codepoint += 0x10000;
        return mb_convert_encoding(pack("N", $codepoint), "UTF-8", "UTF-32");
    }, $s);

    # replace unmatched surrogate pairs with U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER
    return preg_replace('@\xED[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]@', "\xEF\xBF\xBD", $s);
}
```

(You might need `pack("V", ...)` above if you have a big endian CPU...)